# Editing sql query conditions in python

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to automate around 50 queries in a zeppelin notebook. Each query has multiple date conditions that need to be updated every week. I am able to use the api to get the current query, but I don't know how to locate and edit the dates within the string I get. I could just edit the characters at the index, but that would break if anything preceding the date changed in the query. Is there any way to have defined variables in sql. for example

```
date1 = '2023-01-01'
select select e_segment_map['style_guide'] style, count(f_device_id) good
    from events
    where e_key = 'User_Feedback'
    and e_segment_map['feedback'] = 'good'
    and a_receive_day >= date1
    and e_segment_map['type'] = '6'
group by e_segment_map['style_guide']
```

edit:
current python code

```
def getQueries():
    notebookInfo = requests.get('https://query-ntu.perfectcorp.com/zeppelin/api/notebook/2J4GY9RVJ', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('sinfulheinz', 'Tj7g&tENQ/d-PFnX')).json()['body']
    listParagraphs = notebookInfo['paragraphs']

    myPs = []
    for i in range(len(listParagraphs)):
        id = listParagraphs[i]['id']
        text = listParagraphs[i]['text']
        query = text.split('\n')
        myPs.append([id, query])

    print(myPs)
```

Forgot to add that I won't be the end user for this, and the end users won't be proficient in python to constantly make little changes in the python if they need the change their queries.

Comment: please show your python code as well

Comment: I added my python, but its just an api call and my attempts to sort through the json i get .

Comment: how are you executing these queries and against what kind of database?

Comment: Im gonna be honest I'm an intern and this is my first time working with sql so I'm not super sure what you're asking. I'll try my best to answer. The queries are in a zeppelin notebook using spark interpreter. I'm not sure what kind of database, but I have heard AWS in conversation.